# Trouble using try and except

Tags: python, try-catch, except

So, this is my code:

```
import random # Imports the random module
score = 0  
operator = ['*','+','-']
for i in range (1,11):
    print('This is question ',str(i))
    NumOne = random.randint(1,12)
    NumTwo = random.randint(1,12)
    Op = random.choice(operator)
    Answer = eval(str(NumOne) + Op + str(NumTwo))
    while True:
        try:
            userAnswer = int(input('What is the answer to {} {} {}'.format(NumOne,Op,NumTwo)))
            continue
        except ValueError:
            print('That isn\'t a valid input')
    if userAnswer == Answer:
        print('That is the correct answer. You have scored a point')
        score +=1
    else: print('That is the incorrect answer')
print('You have scored',score,'out of 10.\nThat is equal to ',(score/10)*100)
```

Basically, when I run this, it gives me a question. I answer the question, then it asks me the same question again.

So:

What is 1+1?
Then I input 2
And it asks 1+1 again, and this isn't just chance of the random numbers, it repeats several times.

Any help is appreciated on how to ask a different question, I've tried several solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `break` instead of `continue`?

Comment: Yeah, just tried that, and that works, but I was just trying out some more solutions whilst waiting for a reply on this and found that if you use, done = False and while not done instead of while true, and state that done = True once the answer is correct, that works too. However, your answer is more efficient, and a better answer overall, thanks

Comment: @Thom9son `continue` just takes you back to the top of the inner-most loop. Your logic said "if this code doesn't throw a ValueError, run it again ***forever***"

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully clarify some stuff about while loops.

Given a while loop:

```
while x:
    y()
```

The function y() will be called indefinitely until x is `False`.

The keywords *break* and work as following:

```
while x:
    y()
    if z:
        break
```

Will end when x becomes `False` or when z becomes `True`, whichever happens first. This is equivalent to:

```
while x and not z:
    y()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given an infinite loop.
You type While True where it asks you to answer the values will never change because it never gets out what you should do instead is

```
import random # Imports the random module
score = 0  
go = False
operator = ['*','+','-']
for i in range (1,11):
    go = False
    print('This is question ',str(i))
    NumOne = random.randint(1,12)
    NumTwo = random.randint(1,12)
    Op = random.choice(operator)
    Answer = eval(str(NumOne) + Op + str(NumTwo))
    while go != True:
        try:
            userAnswer = int(input('What is the answer to {} {} {}'.format(NumOne,Op,NumTwo)))
            go = True
        except ValueError:
            print('That isn\'t a valid input')
        if userAnswer == Answer:
            print('That is the correct answer. You have scored a point')
            score +=1
        else: 
            print('That is the incorrect answer')
print('You have scored',score,'out of 10.\nThat is equal to ',(score/10)*100)
```

What this does differently is it now asks for a valid answer and if it gets one it goes on to the next question. Hope this helps!